# Using recursion to reverse a phrase

Tags: java, recursion, reverse

I have an assignment that asks me to create a Java program that reverses an input phrase using recursion and outputs it. For example, given an input "DATA STRUCTURES AND ALGORITHMS" the program would output "ALGORITHMS AND STRUCTURES DATA".

One of the restrictions is that no storage or Java collections may be used in the program except for a single local String variable.

I am having trouble understanding how I would read the input data from multiple lines and implement the recursive method on the string. I understand the general concept of recursion, however implementing it into Java is a more difficult task.

Comment: Re: "I understand the general concept of recursion, however implementing it into Java is a more difficult task": Does this mean that you've come up with an appropriate recursive algorithm, and just need help Java-itizing it? If so, please post your pseudocode! :-)

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-string-using-recursion/ - this should give you an idea (in c)

Answer (score 2):

As asked, this solution 'reverses' a string word-by-word, where words are simply separated by a single space character.

```
public class TestClass {

    public static String wordReverse(String s) {
        int idx = s.indexOf(" ");
        if (idx < 0) {
            // no space char found, thus, s is just a single word, so return just s itself
            return s;
        } else {
            // return at first the recursively reversed rest, followed by a space char and the first extracted word
            return wordReverse(s.substring(idx + 1)) + " " + s.substring(0, idx); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(wordReverse("DATA STRUCTURES AND ALGORITHMS"));
    }
}
```

> I am having trouble understanding how I would read the input data from multiple lines

I don't fully understand that point, but if you are asking for how to read user input from stdin then have a look at *System.in*

Comment: While I'm sure you have good intentions, providing straight-out answers to homework questions doesn't help the asker learn anything.

Comment: Leading the OP step by step to his/her own solution is something that I do in forums, but not on a Q&A site, where all have just 'a single shot'. But, indeed, the OP did not seem to have tried very hard before posting, but perhaps he can also learn something from reading and understanding. Anyway, I just liked that example, because in real life I almost never use recursions :)

Comment: I recognize that SO doesn't make it easy to hand-hold through a problem, and while the majority of issues benefit from a clear solution, for problems that are clearly arising from a homework assignment, pseudo-code or answers in other languages can help the student understand the logic without allowing a blind copy-paste. I'm not trying to discourage you from answering questions... I hope you continue to do so, but I also hope Javier passes his class because he understands the material.